# Prove that surfaces $x + 2y – lnz + 4 = 0$ and $x^2 - xy – 8x + z + 5 = 0$ are tangent at $(2,-3,1)$.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

$x + 2y – ln(z) + 4 = 0$

$x^2 - xy – 8x + z + 5 = 0$

$\nabla [1,2,\frac{-1}{z}] $

$\nabla [2x-y-8,-x,1] $

$\nabla(P0) [1,2,-1] $

$\nabla(P0) [-1,-2,1] $

I've stuck at this point and i don't know what to do next.

Comment: Can you show us how you got those $\nabla(P0)  $'s?

Comment: Just edited the question.

Comment: There is a mistake in your second $\nabla(P0)  $. The derivative of $-xy$ with respect to $y$ is $-x$ and not $x$. That makes the $2$ a $-2$ and from here you can probably see it. Compare both $\nabla(P0)$'s

Comment: Yeah thats right. So in this case if i multiply first vector by a scalar -1 then i will have the same vector. What is the end of a proof?

Comment: Both normals are in exact opposite direction and that's what you want at $(2,-3,1)$ for tangency

Comment: You also want the two surfaces to touch at that point: the normals only show that the two tangent planes are parallel.

Comment: @Nick One should certainly check to be sure, but I think we can take as given that the point $(2,-3,1)$ satisfies both equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two surfaces $S_1$ and $S_2$ are tangent at a point $P$ if and only if

$P \in S_1 \cap S_2, \tag{1}$

i.e., $P$ lies in each of $S_1$, $S_2$; and

$T_PS_1 = T_PS_2, \tag{2}$

that is, the tanget planes to $S_1$ and $S_2$ at $P$ are the same.  Taking $S_1$ to be the surface

$f_1(x, y, z) = x + 2y - \ln z + 4 = 0, \tag{3}$

and $S_2$ to be

$f_2(x, y, z) = x^2 - xy - 8x + z + 5 = 0, \tag{4}$

we first verify

$P = (2, -3, 1) \in S_1 \cap S_2 \tag{5}$

by showing

$f_1(P) = f_2(P) = 0; \tag{6}$

we have

$f_1(2, -3, 1)= 2 + 2(-3) -\ln 1 + 4 = 2 - 6 + 4 = 0, \tag{7}$

and

$f_2(2, -3, 1) = 2^2 - 2(-3) - 8(2) + 1 + 5 =  4 + 6 - 16 + 1 + 5= 0; \tag{8}$

thus

$P \in S_1 \cap S_2. \tag{9}$

To see that the tangent planes to $S_1$ and $S_2$ at $P$ coincide, we may show the normal vectors to each surface at $P$ are collinear.  We do this by calculating $\nabla f_1$ and $\nabla f_2$ at $P$, *viz.*

$\nabla f_1 = (1, 2, -\dfrac{1}{z}), \tag{10}$

$\nabla f_2 = (2x - y - 8, -x, 1); \tag{11}$

thus

$\nabla f_1(P) = (1, 2, -1) \tag{12}$

and

$\nabla f_2(P) = (2(2) - (-3) - 8, -2, 1) = (-1, -2, 1); \tag{13}$

we see that

$\nabla f_2(P) = -\nabla f_1(P).  \tag{14}$

Since the normals to $S_1$ and $S_2$ are collinear at the point of intersection $P$, their tangent planes are one and the same there; the surfaces are indeed tangent at $P$.